# redirect on successful sign in - php

Tags: php

I'm trying to redirect my web site to the home page on a successful sign in. I'm using the following code in function.php file to achieve that.

```
function redirect_login_page() {
     $login_page = get_home_url();
     wp_redirect($login_page);
     exit();
}
add_action('login_redirect', 'redirect_login_page');
```

n the localhost this is working correctly, the website is redirected to the home page. But in the live version which is deployed there's a issue where even though the web site is redirected to the home page, it does not maintain the signed in status. If you refresh the page, i can get the signed in status. But this issue does not happen in localhost. In the localhost when the site is redirected, it's showing as signed in. But in the deployed version i have to refresh the page to get that.

What could be the reason for this. I'm new to php and wordpress.,